# Button in center of cell programatically

Tags: ios, swift, button, cell

I am trying to make it so that there is a 'Reset Progress' button inside the **centre** of a cell. Other posts I have found only show how to add a button on the left side or the right side, or require prior steps in the Interface Builder.

How can I add a button in the centre of a cell programmatically without any steps in the Interface Builder?

Comment: Calculate the centre point of the superview (container view) by dividing its height and width by two, then compensate for the buttons frame size. Tada.

Comment: Or learn about how autolayout works and use that to position the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
class YourCell: UITableViewCell {

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    addSubview(button)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

lazy var button: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.backgroundColor = .blue
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 50)
    button.center = self.center
}

@objc func buttonAction() {
    print("Button has been pressed")
}

}
```

Answer (score -2):

1. Download a library called "TinyConstraints" which is a standard in iOS App Development.
2. Import it into your SWIFT File.
3. Add a subview of that button to your tableView Cell.
4. Then try something like: `Button.centreXAxisInSuperView()` or YAxis if you need be, or both... that'll center it for sure.